# Failure to update nested array based on parent array index

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, if-statement, ionic4

I have an array (`answers`) which contains two elements, one an integer(`questionNo`) and another an array(`answer`). I can successfully push new data elements to the array but when I attempt to update the nested array based on the index of the parent array and the value of the integer, i instead end up updating all the nested arrays. Updating only works if there is a single data set (parent array index 0)

The function is:

```
public answers: any  = [];

addItem(qNumber, answerArray)
{

  this.answers.push({
     questionNo: qNumber,
     answer: answerArray
  });
}

updateQnAnswered(qNumber, answerArray){

    for(let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) 
    {
        if(this.answers[i].questionNo === qNumber)
        {
            console.log("update " + i);
            this.answers[i].answer = answerArray;
        }
    }
            
}
```

Scenario:

`updateQnAnswered(2, [true, false])` would be expected to loop through the **answers** array until it finds a match for `this.answers[i].questionNo === 2`. Then update `this.answers[i].answer = [true, false]` but instead of updating the particular array associated with matched **questionNo**, all the arrays are updated instead. Updating only works with index 0 of the parent array

And after index 0, all the nested arrays get updated instead of the intended array linked to `questionNo`.

**UPDATE**

I attempted using `splice` but the problem persists

when I push initially, `this.addItem(0, [false, false])`

```
0:
 answer: (2) ["False", "False"]
 questionNo: 0
```

If i update with `updateQnAnswered(0, ['True', 'True'])`

```
0:
 answer: (2) ["True", "True"]
 questionNo: 0
```

Which is working okay, but when I try to add new element `this.addItem(2, [false, false])` a new element is added but the array values of all indexes are changed

```
0:
 answer: (2) ["False", "False"]
 questionNo: 0
1:
 answer: (2) ["False", "False"]
 questionNo: 2
```

and when I try to update `updateQnAnswered(0, ['False', 'True'])` or  `updateQnAnswered(2, ['True', 'False'])` the array values changed are not for the matched `questionNo`

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hugle-96d8p?file=/src/index.js). I think you should debug or log what `this.answers` is.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide a working example, like a sandbox? Could it be something else resetting these values?

Comment: Hi @Stutje have added pages to sandbox on https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wave-0n8ll?file=/src/app/pages/quiz.page.ts . In quiz.page.ts, the function getBoolvalue is called when the user selects answers on the quiz.page.html. finalanswerboolvalues.models.ts has the function that pushes answers and question numbers to the array

Comment: @Stutje the function getBoolvalue() is supposed to store an array of answers which are passed on for storage before a new set are stored in it. Thats the only other point of failure I can think of right now

Comment: Can u save the sandbox? I'm seeing an empty quiz.page.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222897/discussion-between-appdevnoobie-and-stutje).

Comment: Have checked to make sure all added files are saved. https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wave-0n8ll?file=/src/app/pages/quiz.page.html:0-2668